# How can join two table in yii with standard?

Tags: join, frameworks, yii

I am new in yii framework. and I want to know about take date from two table with join.

I try many times but not solve.

I know the join and know i use it manually. not yii standard.

I want to know **How can join two table in yii** framework with standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yii You want to use join code in $criteria object

e.g.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with =array('customer'=>array('select'=>'{{customer}}.*','joinType'=>'LEFT OUTER JOIN', ), );
```

and use relation function like

public function relations() {
    return array(
        'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id'),
    );
   }

I think it solve your question

Answer (score -1):

In yii join table is very easy.

You want to join code in $criteria object

e.g.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->with =array('customer'=>array('select'=>'{{customer}}.*','joinType'=>'LEFT OUTER JOIN', ), );
```

and use relation function like

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id'),
    );
}
```

I think it solve your question